# How do I add and remove classes to multiple child elements nested in an UL with a single click using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, onclick

I want to start by apologizing for such a long question, I just hope I wont make it difficult to understand as a result.

I have created a side bar with three Menu elements in an UL which expand to show child elements, change background color and remove hover effect when clicked. I did this by defining a function that adds and remove classes containing relevant properties when the menu element is clicked.

The four specific things that I want the sidebar to do but cant seem to get it to do are as follows;

1. only one selected/clicked item to expand at a time while all the
   rest of the unselected menu elements are collapsed. That means if I
   click the first item, it expands and when I click the second one,
   the first one collapses while the one I clicked expands etc.
2. The selected/clicked element changes its background color to
   indicate it's selected.
3. The selected/clicked element has no hover effect on the text while
   the unselected elements have a hover effect of text color change on
   them.
4. I also want the selected menu element be able to toggle the
   expansion on and off not affecting the other elements in the UL.

I think where I'm having most trouble with my code is in the adding and removal of classes especially given that the `<a>`Tags which are nested inside the `<li>` Tags (clicked elements) are where the "hover" class needs to be added/removed, as well as the `<ul>`Tags that expand are also nested inside the clicked elements.

```js
function toggleMenu(e) {
  var kids = document.querySelector("#menuList").children;
  var unselectedLink = document.querySelectorAll(".unselected a");
  var unselectedDropdown = document.querySelectorAll(".unselected ul");

  //adds "unselected" class to all elements exept the selected one
  for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
    kids[i].className = "unselected";
  }

  //adds "menuHover" class to all elements exept the selected element
  for (var i = 0; i < unselectedLink.length; i++) {
    unselectedLink[i].className = "menuHover";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < unselectedDropdown.length; i++) {
    unselectedDropdown[i].classList.remove("show")
  }

  //adds "selected" class, removes "menuHover" class and adds "toggle" to the selected element
  e.className = "selected";
  document.querySelector(".selected a").classList.remove("menuHover");
  document.querySelector(".selected ul").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-bar {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 42px;
}

.side-text {
  color: #C5C5C5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  line-height: 40px;
}

nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: #C5C5C5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 43px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 80px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.submenu-item:hover {
  background: #1e1e1e!important;
}


/*...........selected and show..................*/

.selected {
  background-color: #255DAA;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}


/*...........unselected and hover..................*/

.unselected {
  color: #1e1e1e;
}

.menuHover:hover {
  color: #255DAA;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidebar">
  <div class="menu-bar">
    <label class="side-text">MENU</label>
  </div>
  <ul id="menuList">
    <li class="selected" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
      <a href="#" class="" id="staff-btn">Staff</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">New Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View Staff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="unselected" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
      <a href="#" id="notes-btn" class="menuHover">Notes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">New Note</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Notes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="unselected" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
      <a href="#" class="menuHover" id="tasks-btn">Tasks</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">New Tasks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Task</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</nav>
```

I am quite close but somehow, logically I am doing things the wrong way with the JavaScript, so any adjustments to the code to make it reach all four of the above goals will be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Hi Hillary, your issue could be solved completely with (simple, 4 rules) CSS only. This depends on requirement 5): when a user clicks outside the menu (anywhere in the browser viewport, actually) may the selected menu item be closed or must it stay open? When 'closed' is okay, then CSS only could be the way to go.

Comment: I want the selected menu item to remain open if a user clicks outside the menu, it should only toggle close when they click in the menu only, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this:

If the element was selected, just unselect it

If it wasnt, unselect all elements and select the clicked element

```js
function toggleMenu(el) {
  if (el.classList.contains("selected")) {
    el.classList.remove("selected");
    el.classList.add("unselected");
  }
  else {
    for (const child of document.getElementById("menuList").children) {
      child.classList.remove("selected");
      child.classList.add("unselected");
    }
    el.classList.remove("unselected");
    el.classList.add("selected");
  }
}
```

**Edit 1**
You can use the following css to unhide the submenu of a selected menuitem:

```css
.selected ul {
  display: block;
}
```

**Edit 2**
I went to the trouble of actually implementing it.

```js
function toggleMenu(el) {
  if (el.classList.contains("selected")) {
    el.classList.remove("selected");
    el.classList.add("unselected");
  }
  else {
    for (const child of document.getElementById("menuList").children) {
      child.classList.remove("selected");
      child.classList.add("unselected");
    }
    el.classList.remove("unselected");
    el.classList.add("selected");
  }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-bar {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 42px;
}

.side-text {
  color: #C5C5C5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* menu */

.menu {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu-item {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.menu-item a {
  position: relative;
  color: #C5C5C5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 43px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* submenu */

.submenu {
  position: static;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.submenu-item a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 80px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.submenu-item:hover {
  background: #1e1e1e;
}

/* selected and unselected */

.selected {
  background-color: #255DAA;
}

.selected .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.unselected {
  color: #1e1e1e;
}

.unselected:hover a {
  color: #255DAA;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidebar">
  <div class="menu-bar">
    <label class="side-text">MENU</label>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu" id="menuList">
    <li class="menu-item selected" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
      <a href="#" id="staff-btn">Staff</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">New Staff</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">View Staff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item unselected" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
      <a href="#" id="notes-btn">Notes</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">New Note</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">Edit Notes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item unselected" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
      <a href="#" id="tasks-btn">Tasks</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">New Tasks</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">Edit Task</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but how do I then add and remove 
"menuHover" and "show" classess to the <a> and <ul> Tags nested inside the menu elements as well when the toggleMenu function is called onclick?

Comment: You should be able to do any styling using pure css, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much especially for going through the trouble of implementing it. This is very clear and makes so much sense. I see how my error was on not utilizing the CSS and focusing on JS only. thanks again for the help and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to the accepted answer, here two different approaches I was working on...

`#menuList li` is a container for a list of `<a>` menu items which have adjacent `<ul>` sub-menu-items. For easy selection with CSS I assigned class `.menu-item` to those `<a>`.

The **CSS logic** for both versions is essentially equal:

- set the `.menu-item` adjacent `ul` sub-menu-items hidden by default
- define `:hover` colors
- define colors for a selected `.menu-item` and adjacent `ul` (either `:focus` or `.selected` is true)
- make `.menu-item` adjacent `ul` sub-menu-items visible when a `.menu-item` gets selected (ditto)

**Difference:** for CSS only we use the `:focus` selector, for CSS with Javascript we use class `.selected`.

**CSS only** (automatic *focus* and *blur*)

An `<a>` gets focus when clicked (like button, input, etc. `:focus` is *true*). When the user clicks/taps outside the focussed element it automatically loses focus again (gets *blurred* and `:focus` is *false*, as in *:not(:focus) = 'blur'*). We can use the CSS `:focus` selector to handle user clicks and modify elements, [MDN: ':focus'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).

**CSS with Javascript** (*focus* and *blur* on request)

The OP wants a selected `.menu-item` and its adjacent `ul` sub-menu-items to stay visible until the user specifically deselects it again. This cannot be done with the `:focus` selector, so we ignore that selector and use class `.selected` instead to handle *focus* and *blur* requirements ourselves, [MDN: HTMLElement.blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur).

The **Javascript logic** is fairly straightforward:

Attach a 'click'-`eventListener` ([MDN: Element: click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)) to main container `#menuList` handling:

- when a `.menu-item` gets selected and it is the currently `.selected` then *blur* it (`menuItemBlur()`)
- otherwise

  - when we have a previously selected `.menu-item` open, *blur* that first (`menuItemBlur()`)
  - and then *focus* the newly selected `.menu-item` (`menuItemFocus()`)

**Changes to OP code**

- removed unneeded CSS
- removed unneeded `class` attributes from HTML
- changed `href="#"` in `<#menuList li a>` to `href="javascript:void(0)"` to prevent it from creating an entry in the browser history (sub-menu-items will still create an entry).

The below **snippet** is heavily commented and should be self-explanatory.

```js
'use-strict';

var activeItem; // Holds the currently '.selected''.submenu' (null/undefined if none)

// Attach 'click' event listener to the #menuList
document.getElementById('menuList')
    .addEventListener('click', function(e) { menuItemToggle(e.target) });

function menuItemToggle(el) {
    if (el.classList.contains('menu-item2')) {   // When a '.menu-item' gets clicked (not its kids)
        if (el.classList.contains('selected')) { //  and it is the '.selected''.menu-item'
            menuItemBlur(el);                    // then close it and remove focus()
        }
        else {
            if (activeItem)               // When there is a currently selected '.menu-item'
                menuItemBlur(activeItem); // then deactivate it

            menuItemFocus(el);            // Now activate the clicked `.menu-item`
        };
    };

    function menuItemBlur(el) {
        el.classList.remove("selected"); // Set the '.menu-item' to not '.selected'
        activeItem = null;               // and remove the reference to it
        el.blur();                       // Remove focus from element for CSS ':focus'
        // ...extend with other 'Blur' stuff...
    };
    function menuItemFocus(el) {
        el.classList.add("selected");    // Set the '.menu-item' to '.selected'
        activeItem = el;                 // and save a reference to it
        // ...extend with other 'Focus' stuff...
    };
};
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-bar {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 42px;
}

.side-text {
  color: #c5c5c5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  line-height: 40px;
}

nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 43px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 80px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

/*************/
/* ADDED CSS */
/*************/
/* All classes starting with "menu-item" */
[class^="menu-item"] + ul   { display: none  } /* hide adjacent UL */
[class^="menu-item"]:hover  { color: #255daa } /* hover color */

a + ul li a:hover           { color: #c5c5c5; background-color: #1b1b1b }
/*
    menu-item adjacent sub-menu-items hover colors
    Here the generic form is used, but it would
    probably be more clear to be specific and use:

     - either .menu-item1:focus + ul li a:hover
     -     or .menu-item2.selected + ul li a:hover
*/
/*
    ':focus' version
    
    This version uses the CSS ':focus' without any Javascript.

    Main difference with the '.selected' version below is that when the
    user clicks outside the '.menu-item', the '.menu-item' looses focus
    and therefore gets hidden again (as :focus is no longer true). 
*/
.menu-item1:focus,
.menu-item1:focus + ul { color: #e6e6e6; background-color: #255DAA } /* focus colors */
.menu-item1:focus + ul { display: block } /* show adjacent UL */

/*
    '.selected' version, with Javascript.

    Basically the same CSS, but now using class '.selected' instead of ':focus'.
    Closing occurs only on user specific 'click'. 
*/
.menu-item2.selected,
.menu-item2.selected + ul { color: #e6e6e6; background-color: #255DAA } /* focus colors */
.menu-item2.selected + ul { display: block } /* show adjacent UL */

/*********************/
/* for demo use only */
/*********************/
nav h3 {
    color: rgba(100, 149, 237,.9); /* CornflowerBlue */
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left: 43px;
}
.anchor {
    color: white;
    padding-left: 43px;
}
.content {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 5rem 300px;
}
/* preferred globals */
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }
body                    { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="menu-bar">
        <label class="side-text">MENU</label>
    </div>

    <h3>test</h3>
    <a class="anchor" href="javascript:void(0)">some '.sidebar' &lt;a&gt;</a>

    <ul id="menuList">
        <h3>:focus version</h3>
        <li>
            <a class="menu-item1" href="javascript:void(0)">Staff</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View Staff</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu-item1" href="javascript:void(0)">Notes</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Note</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edit Notes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu-item1" href="javascript:void(0)">Tasks</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Tasks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edit Task</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <h3>.selected version</h3>
        <li>
            <a class="menu-item2" href="javascript:void(0)">Staff</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View Staff</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu-item2" href="javascript:void(0)">Notes</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Note</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edit Notes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu-item2" href="javascript:void(0)">Tasks</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Tasks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edit Task</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content">
    <h3><b>Note</b></h3>
    <p>
       This demo uses two different approaches interchangeably creating a quirky behaviour,
       which under normal circumstances would not exist.
    </p>
    <p>To reproduce:</p>
    <ul>
       <li>select a <i>':focus version'</i> menu item first
       <li>then select a <i>'.selected version'</i> menu item
    </ul>
    <p>
       As you can see, the selected <i>':focus version'</i> loses focus and a second
       'click' is needed to activate the <i>'.selected version'</i> menu item.
       This is because the first click event of the <i>'.selected version'</i> gets consumed by the blur event
       of the <i>':focus version'</i>.
    </p>
    <p>Just so you know...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for these alternative approaches, not just insightful but I'm also learning a lot from them. Great to see how we have multiple ways to approach a single problem in using just CSS and also as a combination with JS. Much appreciated.