# Do not change the focus of list item in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have a html list like this:

```
 <ul id="componentList" class="at-list">
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 1</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 2</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 3</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 4</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 5</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 6</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Now I can focus on list items by clicking them and clear the focus by clicking anywhere on the page. What I want to do is that clear the focus of list items only when I click on other items of the list. How can I do this? Thankyou.

**Update: **
The css file:

```
.at-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    left: -5%;
}

.at-list-item {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #454545AA;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease-in-out, font-weight 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: font-size 0.3s ease-in-out, font-weight 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.at-list-item:hover {
    color: #454545AA;
}

.at-list-item:focus {
    color: #fdb715;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: css missing, can't replicate

Comment: I added the css

Comment: Such a behavior will soon turn to a nightmare to maintain, if you've other focusable elements on the page too.

Comment: @Teemu Yes I do have other other focusable elements on the page, what should I do now :/

Comment: It might help, if you'd marked all the focusable elements with a common class, or added `tabindex` attribute to all of them. Listen `focusout` event on the closest common ancestor element of the focusables, check if the current active elemen is one of the focusables, and if it's not, return the focus to the last focused element.

Comment: Tnx @Teemu, I will try to test that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strategy

What you essentially need is to ignore the default (built-in) HTML/CSS element (de)focussing mechanism. So, except for `:hover`, we are going to ignore that mechanism and implement our own little strategy:

- introduce the classes `.selected` and `.unselected` so we can use CSS to modify some properties of the 'at-list-item' that incorporates either class
- create a Javascript handler that handles the toggling of the forementioned classes when a menu item is clicked.
- attach the handler to each menu item
- Ignore `:active` and `:focus` in CSS (for now, unless you want to modify properties when those events get triggered)

Code changes/additions

- moved font color/size handling of `.at-list-item` to a separate CSS line
- Introduced CSS for classes `.selected` and `.unselected`
- Added (vanilla) Javascript handling the click toggle

Code

```js
// Add a click eventlistener to each menu item
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.at-list-item')).
forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => toggleMenu(el)));

function toggleMenu(el) {
    if (el.classList.contains("selected")) {
      el.classList.remove("selected");
      el.classList.add("unselected");
    }
    else {
      for (const child of document.getElementById("componentList").children) {
        child.classList.remove("selected");
        child.classList.add("unselected");
      }
      el.classList.remove("unselected");
      el.classList.add("selected");
    }
}
```

```css
.at-list {
    list-style-type: none;
/*    position: relative;
    left: -5%;
*/
}

.at-list-item {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #454545AA;
}

.at-list-item:hover {
    color: #454545AA;
}

.at-list-item,
.at-list-item.unselected {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.at-list-item.selected {
    color: #fdb715;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul id="componentList" class="at-list">
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 1</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 2</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 3</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 4</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 5</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 6</li>
    <li tabindex="1" class="at-list-item">Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That was the answer thank you so much, It's working like a charm.

Comment: Your welcome! This answer was a simplified adaptation of another answer I gave on SO. Have a look at [SO63210777](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63305314/2015909).